# Inconsistency of pickle.load() and pickle.dump()

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, keras, pickle

I'm building the neural network and should test in on **modified** CIFAR-10.  I have used `keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()` for retrieving the dataset and then parsed it in a dict using `pickle.load(datafile, encoding='bytes')`. After some modifications I've written the images in keras-like format using `pickle.dump()`.

I noticed that the resulting file after `pickle.dump()` is **53 bytes bigger** then the source file. Even if I don't make any modifications and use the `dump()` right away after `load()` the resulting file has extra 53 bytes. Looks like the structure of the resulting file isn't violated because I'm able to restore images, labels, filenames from it and they are correct. But if I'm learning and testing the neural network (even the simplest NN from the [example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py)!) I'm getting very bad score (~0.5).

1. Please help me to figure out how the loading-dumping affects the NN's result if the structure in general doesn't change?
2. How I can load and dump to leave the structure and the size of files without changes? ***How to avoid the inconsistency of load-dump operation?***

P.S. Looks like the `dump()` writes some header to the file and doesn't write it if the header already exists (i've tried to apply load-dump twice but the size was changes only at first applying). But how I can avoid writing this header?

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me to figure out how the loading-dumping affects the NN's
>   result if the structure in general doesn't change?

If the structure does not change, it has no effect to the network. You can simple dump with human readable outputs and compare the files. First read about protocols [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

> How I can load and dump to leave the structure and the size of files
>   without changes? How to avoid the inconsistency of load-dump
>   operation?

there is no real inconsistancy, its probably just using another protocol or attaching headers. You should not deal with these internals. If you want to make your model human readable or put it under version control, you can use json or another human readbale protocol. (e.g. simplejson)